# I was using Winrar but i need to use 7z now. Can u provide an alternative for 'winrar a -ep1 -idq -r -y '

Tags: 7-zip, winrar

Winrar.exe a -ep1 -idq -r -y filename

-ep1 is used to remove base folder while extracting.

So i need the command for excluding that
one.

Hope this is much clear.

Comment: It might help to explain what the `ep1` and `idq` options actually do and why you need them.

Comment: I'm guessing you're missing some punctuation? The final paragraph looks like a few different thoughts without a period between them and the question is confusing. Please use the EDIT button and make your question more clear, including a better and more clear description of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hi @Mokubai-idq ... enable quiet mode to display only error messages,
-ep1 ... exclude base directory from specified file/folder names

Comment: @AshithaA rather than replying in comments you should add the information to your question.

Comment: @Mokubai what all information need to be updated???

Answer (score 0):

**a:** add files

**-tzip:** Use zip format

**-r:** recursive

**-y:** assume yes to all questions

**-bse0:** No error messages

**-bso0:** No output messages

**-bsp0:** No progress messages

```
7z.exe a -tzip -r -y -bse0 -bso0 -bsp0 Archive.zip "C:\path\*"
```